# Field Label for Content Type

Tags: entities, nodes

I need to find where the field label for a content type is stored within the database. I tried the field_config_instance, it's not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, you just need to look a bit harder ;)

Have a look at the serialised array in the `data` column of that table. You'll find the label for the field listed in there.

If you want to extract this in code the best way is to use the field API functions, it saves you having to mess about with the serialised array directly:

```
$entity_type = 'node';
$field_name = 'body';
$bundle = 'article';

$info = field_info_instance($entity_type, $field_name, $bundle);
$label = $info['label'];
```

Comment: I see, so that's where drupal stores it. But I have a problem now. I wrote my own function to generate a xml file based on url parameter. A couple fields are named with integer values, one of them is like "0+". And it gives me error when my function tries to generate xml. Is there anyway to pull the label from the data column without using drupal or field API? Or is there a way to access the API outside of drupal installation?

Comment: Without using Drupal/field API, sure, but definitely not without using PHP. The string is a serialised PHP array so only PHP (or a crazy-assed custom MySQL parser, of which I don't think there are any for this purpose) will be able to extract it again

Comment: My function is in PHP

Comment: In that case you're fine...grab the contents of the `data` column from `field_config_instance` using whatever method you want, and run: `$info = unserialize($data_column_value); $label = $info['label'];`